# mql4 } not all control paths return a value

Tags: mql4

I have taken this function from another mql4 script. The other script compiles absolutely fine with no error. Strangely, now that I have copied this function into my script I get the error `} not all control paths return a value`

I understand the concept of return a value but not sure when there is a compile difference between the scripts

```
int ModifyOrder(int ord_ticket,double op, double price,double tp, color mColor)
{
    int CloseCnt, err;

    CloseCnt=0;
    while (CloseCnt < 3)
    {
       if (OrderModify(ord_ticket,op,price,tp,0,mColor))
       {
         CloseCnt = 3;
       }
       else
       {
          err=GetLastError();
          Print(CloseCnt," Error modifying order : (", err , ") " + ErrorDescription(err));
         if (err>0) CloseCnt++;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the difference is in `#property strict`. if using strict mode, you have to redeclare local variables, return value from every function (except `void`, of course) and some other differences. 
In your example the function has to be ended with `return CloseCnt;` or maybe something else.

No way to declare non-strict mode - simply do not declare the strict one. 
Once you declared it, it is applied to that file, and included into other files if importing.